# How to add logs in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am new to django I want to print log information in my console how to do that. and also what is the use of that things in django, why we need that one.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is *that things*? Please follow [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log stuff to your console, javascript's `console.log()` would be the way to do that. With Django, `print` statements will show up in your terminal window where the server is running.